# Вывод новостей с сайта

Tags: delphi-7, сеть

Можно ли сделать так, что бы информация со страницы выводилась частично, к примеру только выделенное красным на рисунке, а по нажатию на какую либо новость, запускался браузер, а в нем открывалась окно нажатой ссылки.
[image: img]

Пытался сделать примерно так: [**Проект**](http://webfile.ru/6293736)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно.

Получаешь код страницы парсишь ее на части и часть которую тебе нужно и выводишь.

Показывайте свой код, будем смотреть где что у Вас не так.

Ну глядя на ваш проект в Вашем случае нужно добавить одну строку и в итоге код в обработчике на кнопку будет такой

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
memo1.Text:= StringReplace(memo1.Text, './Áåëîðóññêèé ïîðòàë TUT.BY_files/', 'http://img.tyt.by/320x0s/n/0c/1/',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
 LoadHTMLContent(WebBrowser1, Memo1.Text);
end;
```

Comment: то что крокозябрами это Беларусский портал

Comment: А как сделать что бы оно обновлялось, т.е. новости меняются раз в сутки и в приложении тоже менялись?

Comment: Ну таким образом как вы в меом вводили код так и делайте только раз в сутки

Comment: Каким способом можно сделать так, что бы обновление шло автоматически? Хотя бы в каком направлении искать подскажите.

Comment: Напрвление INDY (для получения кода) и Timer Для отсчета времени
Оба слова в связке со словом Delphi в гугле творят чудеса